# Derviation of the gradient for $E(f_\vec{w}) = (X\vec{w} - \vec{y})^{T}\cdot (X\vec{w} - \vec{y})$.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I am tying to derive the following gradient
$$\nabla_{\vec{w}}E(f_{\vec{w}}) = 2X^{T}X\vec{w} - 2X^{T}\vec{y}$$
from this formula $$E(f_\vec{w}) = (X\vec{w} - \vec{y})^{T}\cdot (X\vec{w} - \vec{y})$$

where $X$ is an $n \times d$ vandermonde matrix, $d$ is the degree of the polynomial and $\vec{w}$ is an $d \times 1$ matrix.

This is what I have tried to do,
\begin{align*} 
\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec{w}} E(f_{\vec{w}}) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial \vec{w}}\Big((X\vec{w} - \vec{y})^{T}\cdot (X\vec{w} - \vec{y})\Big) \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial \vec{w}}\Big( \vec{w}^T X^TX\vec{w} - \vec{w}^T X^{T}\vec{y} - \vec{y}^TX\vec{w} + \vec{y}^T \vec{y}\Big) \\
&= 2X^TX\vec{w} - X^{T}\vec{y} - \underbrace{\vec{y}^TX}_{\text{$\stackrel{?}{=} X^{T}\vec{y}$}}
\end{align*}
Now, I am almost there, however, I cannot make any sense of the last term in the last equation. Is it true that $X^{T}\vec{y} = \vec{y}^TX$? If yes how? If not, what is wrong with the derivation?

Comment: The quantity $w^TX^Ty$ is a scalar and therefore equal to its own transpose $y^TXw$. Exclusively using the first form yields $$\eqalign{E &= w^TX^TXw-2w^TX^Ty+y^Ty\cr\frac{\partial E}{\partial w} &= 2X^TXw-2X^Ty}$$

Comment: @greg Thanks for the answer, it makes sense now. Are there any resources you could suggest on the topic of matrix calculus or calculus with linear algebra. Moreover, I would appreciate it if you could write your comment as an answer so I can vote it as an answer and close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A scalar value equals its own transpose 
$$y^TXw = (y^TXw)^T = w^TX^Ty$$
Use this result to simplify the cost function before finding the gradient
$$\eqalign{
 E &= w^TX^TXw - 2w^TX^Ty + y^Ty \cr
\frac{\partial E}{\partial w} &= 2X^TXw - 2X^Ty \cr
}$$